# Material-ui disable swipe in LeftNav

Tags: material-ui

The LeftNav in current version of material-ui (v 0.14.4) can be set to `disableSwipeToOpen`. But there is no way to disable swipe to close. In my case, I have a slider within the LeftNav. The swiping gesture always gets messed up between the slider and LeftNav itself. I'm wondering if there is a way to disable swipe gesture for LeftNav all together?

Comment: Does the problem exist in v15.x? If so, then it sounds like an ideal case for you to fix it and submit a pull request. I suspect that you can see what it does to disable it on open and then duplicate that.

Comment: I didn't check it with v 0.15.x. Looking at v 0.15.x API, there isn't a prop for disabling all swipe gestures. However, I did figure a hacky workaround by calling `this._leftNav._disableSwipeHandling()` in parent component's `componentDidMount()` AND `componentDidUpdate()`, where `this._leftNav` is the `ref` to the LeftNav component, obtained by `ref={(ref) => this._leftNav = ref ? ref : null}`. I'd love to have `disableSwipe` exposed as a prop, though.